# What do they mean by "how moist the air is" in this definition?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-in-context

> **Relative Humidity** indicates how moist the air is

How can the air be moist (wet) if it is in gas form? That doesn't make any sense to me, but I am misunderstanding something.  If anyone wonders what my source is I found it on [this website](http://ww2010.atmos.uiuc.edu/(Gh)/guides/mtr/cld/dvlp/rh.rxml).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about learning English (does not ask about the words or phrasing in the example). Rather, it asks a science question (how air can hold moisture).

Answer (score 3):

If something is moist, it means that it is slightly wet, but the air itself is not actually wet. Humidity refers to the amount of water vapor in the air. So, how moist the air is tells us how much water vapor there is in the air. They've got an entire article on Wikipedia specifically dedicated to an explanation of the concept of humidity. Click [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humidity) for details if you're interested.

Comment: Cookie Monster is exactly right. Referring to the air as "moist" doesn't mean it is "wet", but let it touch a cold window pane, for example, and you'll soon see the moisture.

Comment: in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humidity they're saying water vapors can't be seen..But here do you see this gas? it's water vapour http://prntscr.com/dt3eue  how can it not be seen..?

Comment: Look, here at English Language Learners, we primarily deal with questions that are only relevant to the English language, not phenomena studied by physics. So, I really could care less weather water vapor can or cannot be seen.

Comment: How do you know this is a concept studied by Physics and not Chemistry? just asking.

Comment: How do I know that? As a matter of fact, I don't. It's just, shall we say, an educated guess that's somewhat based on my personal experience studying those subjects in high school and a little bit in college.

Answer (score 1):

"Air" includes all that is suspended within it; that can't be distinguished from it, using one's unaided senses.  For example, air can be "wet" or "dusty" because we can't distinguish individual, minimally required particles of humidity or dust needed to characterize the air as wet or dusty (as a general rule).